# Factory flow. How does it work

Tags: angularjs

Since I started to write code with AngularJS, I've been using factories and found them very useful.
I thought that they work like this (pseudo code):

```
FACTORY NAMESPACE {
    PRIVATE FIELDS AND FUNCTIONS
    RETURN {
        INTERFACES TO ACCESS PRIVATE DATA
    }
}
```

I thought that the expressions in *return* evaluates only when accessed directly, but, it seems that I didn't get it right.

I understand that the factories and services are very bottom of AngularJS and maybe someone thinks that this question shouldn't be here because it's trivial, and yet...

[I created this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OEL8fTUdDiUrbgQKKxTq?p=preview), I tried to find out why the variable changed inside factory code, won't keep its value after, when being accessed from outside, and what I found out confused me even more, **the code inside of every return functions evaluates before anything else and it doesn't get called when it should be (by my logic)! Is. Is that designed that way, and if so, why?**

Snippet from plnkr

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[])

myApp.factory('_gl', [function () {
    // Private fields
    var _x;

    function _somefunc(){
      // This function evaluates even before the code of 'ctrl'
      _x = 6;
      console.log("changed:"+ _x);
    }

    return  {
      x:_x,
      changeX:_somefunc()
    }  
}]);

myApp.controller('ctrl', ['_gl',  function (_gl) {
  _gl.x=2;
  console.log("x init: " + _gl.x);
  _gl.changeX(); // This does nothing at all
  console.log("x after change: " + _gl.x);
}]);

/* Expected output
x init: 2
changed: 6
x after change:6
/*

/* Actual output
x init: 2
changed:6
x after change: 2
*/
```

---

**Result:**

After all that I found out from @dfsq (that right way is to use getters and setters), I came to the conclusion that although it can make some memory overhead, using simple JS global vars will do for me better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the code inside of every return functions evaluates before anything else

Of course, because *you are* executing it with `_somefunc()`.

It should be:

```
return  {
  x: _x,
  changeX: _somefunc
}
```

Note, that there should be no `()` after `_somefunc`, which is invocation operator. You want `changeX` to be a reference to `_somefunc`, not result of `_somefunc` execution (`_somefunc()`).

Comment: Thank you, it solved half of the problem, but other half is still here: the changed value of _x, won't persist when it's accessed with _gl.x, why?

Comment: `_gl.x` is not going to change when you change `x`. There is no connection between them. Primitive types are passed by value, which means that after initial assignment `x:_x` changes to `x` won't affect `_gl.x`. Another way to put it: `_gl.x` is a copy of `x`, but not `x`. If you want `_gl.x` to change, you need to change it `_gl.x = 6` inside `_somefunc`.

Comment: but I cannot change _gl.x while I'm still in the 'constructor' of this _gl - it's not created yet, right?

Comment: I just need to implement 'static' fields in one common factory, so I can use its fields throughout the app. I would be most grateful if you suggest any good idea to solve this problem

Comment: You should not expose (make public) primitive types. Just expose a getter and you are fine. `return {getX: function() { return x; }, changeX: _someFunction }`.

Comment: so I need to use two methods for each variable, now I understand. Thank you very much, this talk was very productive for me, I learned a lot, good to have you here ;)